# Редактирование тегов mp3

Tags: android

Хочу организовать у себя в плеере возможность редактировать тэги песни. Может кто знает ссылку на реализацию?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь поиском. Например сразу нашелся вот такой пост http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707572/how-to-get-and-set-change-id3-tag-metadata-of-audio-files

Comment: И кстати этот вопрос советую или уточнить или удалить